# Stretching polygon by Adorner in wpf

Tags: wpf, polygon, adorner

I have a polygon with outline (adorner has four thumb in four corners ).
When I change with or height by thumbs the polygon points doesn't change their values
but the polygon change its Width and height well.

I mean if I have polygon has points ((10,20),(50,160),(300,10))
when I stretch the polygon the points doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

It will never change. As per `WPF`, you are only scaling (changing width and height of) polygon (`UIElement`). You might have specified `Stretch="Fill"`, don't use it in this case. Create [Adroners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) and edit points using them visually OR simply just update each point on Width or Height change.

Comment: thank you 
yes i specified Stretch="Fill" and i as you said i will change the position of the points manually